# Store an object created by the exception when it is raised, Python

Tags: python, exception

Here is my exception class,

```
class SampleError(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = Stack()
```

Here is the function,

```
def f(x):
    raise SampleError
```

When f(x) is run, how to I store the stack that is created while SampleError is raised.

Thanks as always!

Comment: By "store", do you mean, into a variable?

Answer (score 3):

If by "store" you mean assign to a variable for analysis, use [`sys.exc_info()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info):

```
import sys
try:
    f()
except:
    exc_type, exc, trace = sys.exc_info() # trace is the traceback object
```

Please note the warning regarding the circular references in the spec.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module. It will enable you to generate a traceback from any instance. You can also store in in any form you want after some post processing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to do something like this???

import traceback

```
class SampleError(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = traceback.extract_stack()

def f(x):
    raise SampleError

try:
    f(5);
except SampleError, e:
    print e.history
    out = traceback.format_list(e.history)
    print out[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access exception attributes:

```
try:
    f()
except SampleError, error:
    history = error.history
```